# Prove, that $f: S_{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is a surjection.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality

For $k>0$ define

$S_{k} := \{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|<k,\ \ \ \ k\cdot y>|x|\}\subset\mathbb{C}$

Let $f(z)=\exp(1/z)\ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ z\neq 0$ Prove, that $f: S_{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is a surjection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $w=\exp(1/z)$ has the solutions 
$$z=\frac{1}{\log w} = \frac{1}{\ln|w| +i\arg w}=\frac{\ln|w|-i\arg w}{(\ln|w|)^2+(\arg w)^2},
$$
where $\arg w$ is any argument of $w$. By choosing $\arg w$ large enough negative, $|z| \approx 0$ and the real part of $z$ will be small compared to the imaginary part. Hence $z$ will be in $S_k$.